# div background repeat to left only

Tags: css, xhtml, html

Is there any way to set the background-repeat property of the div element to repeat it only to the left or the right, only to the one side of the page? Like I start the background image on the center of the div and repeat it only to the left side.

Comment: No, this isn't possible currently (so far as I know). `repeat-x` covers the whole axis, unfortunately. `background-position` and a very large image might let you achieve what you want, though.

Comment: are you looking for the background-repeat:repeat-y option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sort of possible using nested divs. Take a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YSCHW/). Do let me know if you need any more help :-)

Comment: Good to see a working solution! Thanks for the upvote too :-)